# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar una lista en un fichero?

Tags: python

este es mi codigo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import os


data = open("Text.txt", "r")
lista = list(data)
archivo = open("Text.txt","w")
salir = False

def mostrar_lista():
    print("")
    print(lista)


def input_str(msg="ingrese una opcion:"):

    while True:
          os.system('cls')
          mostrar_lista()
          cadena = input(msg)

          try:
             valor = str(cadena)
             if valor in ['r','a','s','R','A','S']:
                return valor
                break  
          except ValueError:
                continue


while not salir:

    os.system('cls')
    opcion = input_str("\nPara añadir algo a la lista 'a'\nPara remover algo de la lista 'r'\nPara salir 's':")

    opcion = opcion.lower()            
    if opcion == 'a':

        os.system('cls')
        print("")
        print(lista)
        cosas = input("\nIngrese lo que quiera añadir a la lista:")
        lista.append(str(cosas))


    elif opcion == 'r': 

        os.system('cls')
        print("")
        print(lista)
        cosasR = input("\nIngrese lo que desee remover de la lista:")
        if cosasR in lista:
            lista.remove(str(cosasR))
        else:
            pass

    elif opcion == 's':
        for item in lista:
            archivo.write("%s\n" % item)
        archivo.close()
        data.close()
        salir = True
```

cuando lo ingreso está así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando salgo y entro está así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente? Los ficheros no contienen listas, contienen bytes. Dale a [edit] para añadir más detalles, así como lo que probaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregar en la linea data `.read().splitlines()` para que no importe los saltos de linea como texto:

```
data = open("Text.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
```

Eliminar `data.close()` de la opción Salir "s"

```
elif opcion == 's':
    for item in lista:
        archivo.write("%s\n" % item)
    archivo.close()
    salir = True
```

Comment: yo estoy haciendo un programa que te guarde una lista en un fichero y cuando abras el programa la lista sea igual a la informacion del fichero

Comment: Listo edite mi respuesta! Quedo pendiente si hay mas preguntas :D

Answer (score 3):

Entendiendo una lista como la estructura de datos de Python, esta no puede ser almacenada en un fichero directamente.

El método [write()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=write#file.write) relativo a ficheros espera un string o un buffer de caracteres. Esto quiere decir que, si los elementos de la lista no son de tipo string, deberás convertirlos antes de escribirlos en el fichero.

Además, para que las escrituras se reflejen en el fichero de destino, deberás llamar a flush() o close().

Te pongo un ejemplo, suponiendo una lista de strings y suponiendo que quieras ver cada elemento en una línea separada:

```
archivo = open("Text.txt", "w")
lista = ["Primera línea", "Segunda línea", "Tercera línea"]

for elemento in lista:
    archivo.write(elemento + "\n")

archivo.close()
```

El contenido de Text.txt es

```
Primera línea
Segunda línea
Tercera línea
```

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta y bienvenido a [es.so]! Por cierto, es bueno esperar a que el OP (autor de la pregunta) aporte más esfuerzo, más que nada para que este sitio no sea el lugar donde hacer los deberes a la gente :)

Comment: ¡Gracias @fedorqui! Como has visto, estoy aprendiendo aún a aportar. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez.